# Why converting IBuffer to array doesn't give exact values?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, filestream

I have created Windows Store Audio Record app in which I wanted to save bytes from its buffer so I could process and play it later. But it looks like wrong data is coming from Microsoft implemented function `buffer.ToArry();`.

Converting IBuffer to array gives (this one is example of first buffer of 82 index bytes)

`82,73,70,70,0,0,0,0,87,65,86,69,74,85,78,75,28,...`

bytes where after 4th index there is always zero. And of same stream if I read it after whole stream its bytes are like

`82,73,70,70,138,60,1,0,87,65,86,69,74,85,78,75,28,...`

So why it is not the same? It's supposed to be the same right? Can somebody help me with this? And have correct bytes from buffer.

This is the code for converting buffer to array of bytes:

```
public Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperationWithProgress<uint, uint> WriteAsync(IBuffer buffer)
{
    var z = buffer.ToArray();
    bytes.AddRange(z);// list of byte
    return this.GetOutputStreamAt(this.Position).WriteAsync(buffer);
}
```

This code is giving correct bytes from stream:

```
using (var dataReader = new DataReader(stream2.GetInputStreamAt(0)))
{
    await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)stream2.Size);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)stream2.Size];
    dataReader.ReadBytes(buffer);
}
```

Comment: What is you problem exactly the ToArray()?

Comment: yes, by using buffer.ToArray() gives 82,73,70,70,0,0,0,0,87,65,86,69,74,85,78,75,28,... (which is used for real time byte conversion) and second code gives 82,73,70,70,138,60,1,0,87,65,86,69,74,85,78,75,28,...(which is taken after stopping the stream writing)  why different values are there ?even for the same stream source?

Comment: I have done myself a part of code to try if ToArray() works and it worked but you should post some code with what is your input and how you process it.

Comment: Here is the code I used to test if ToArray() works: http://pastebin.com/sMrvMwvQ